# $\inf_{b\in\mathbf{R},c>0,P(x)\in A}{\dfrac{\int_{b}^{b+c}{|P(x)|dx}}{c^{n+1}}}>0$

Tags: calculus, integration, polynomials

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}^{+}$, $A=\{f(x)|f(x)=x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{1}x+a_{0},a_{i}\in \mathbb{R}\} $. Show that
$$\inf_{b\in\mathbf{R},c>0,P(x)\in A}{\dfrac{\int_{b}^{b+c}{|P(x)|dx}}{c^{n+1}}}>0$$

Comment: With Davide Giraudo's reduction, you see that this inf is actually the distance between $x^n$ and the finite-dimensional subspace of polynomials of degree not greater than $n-1$. With respect to the $L^1$ norm.

Comment: Now in general in a metric space, $d(x,S)=0$ if and only if $x$ belongs to $\overline{S}$. Finally, finite dimensional subspaces over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ are complete, hence closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The map $\tau_b\colon A\to A$, $\tau_b(P)(x):=P(x+b)$ is bijective, hence it's enough to consider the case $b=0$.
2. Making the substitution $ct=x$, we are reduced to show that 
   $$\inf_{a_0,\dots,a_{n-1},c}\int_0^1\left|t^n+\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}a_jt^jc^{j-n}\right|dt>0.$$
3. Putting $b_j:=a_jc^{j-n}$, we actually have to show that 
   $$\inf_{b_0,\dots,b_{n-1}}\int_0^1\left|t^n+\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}b_jt^j\right|dt>0.$$
4. To conclude, we use functional analysis as notes Julien in the comments, that is, we view the latest infimum as the distance of $t^n$ to the finite-dimensional hence closed subspace of polynomials of degree smaller than $n-1$ for the norm $N(f):=\int_0^1|f(x)|dx$.

Comment: Nice reduction, +1. You can even drop the $c$, by replacing $a_jc^{j-n}$ by $a_j$.

Comment: Can you show a complete proof of it? thank you very much!